# Assigning values to a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe as below:

```
Col1
ABC
ABCD
XYZ Ju21
```

I want assign the value to a new column in this dataframe:

- If Col1 does not contain space, then copy Col1(row value) to Col2
- If Cole contains a space, then extract the string before first space and assign it to Col2

Can it be done using regex or any pandas function? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what was your result?

Comment: Col2 = np.where(df[Col1].str.contains(' '),<I want to extract string before space>,Col1). I need help in extracting the part before the first space.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution combining `str.contains`, `str.split` and `lambda` within `np.where`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2,3],'Col1':['ABC','ABCD','XYZ Ju21']})

df1['Col2'] = np.where(df1['Col1'].str.contains(' '),df1['Col1'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x[0]),df1['Col1'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   index      Col1  Col2
0      1       ABC   ABC
1      2      ABCD  ABCD
2      3  XYZ Ju21   XYZ
```